# Can you share Docker containers?

Tags: docker

I have been trying to figure out why one might choose adding every "step" of their setup to a `Dockerfile` which will create your container in a certain state.

The alternative in my mind is to just create a container from a simple base image like `ubuntu` and then (via shell input) configure your container the way you'd like.

**But can you share containers?** If you can only share images with Docker then I'd understand why one would want every step of their container setup listed in a `Dockerfile`.

The reason I ask is because I imagine there is some amount of headache involved with porting shell commands, file changes for configs, etc. to correct `Dockerfile` syntax and have them work correctly? But as a novice with Docker I could be overestimating the difficulty of that task.

**EDIT**: I suppose another valid reason for having the `Dockerfile` with each setup step is for documentation as to the initial state of the container. As opposed to being given a container in a certain state, but not necessarily having a way to know what all was done from the container's image base state.

Comment: What would you suggest for when you want to rebuild your image with a very slight change? Half the point of Docker and the like is to automate as much as possible, and have reproducible builds of everything.

Comment: @JonSkeet valid point. If you'd like to elaborate in an answer I'll accept.

Comment: I'd rather not, as only a casual docker user. I suspect another user may well be able to write a better answer.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **But can you share containers?** If you can only share images with Docker then I'd understand why one would want every step of their container setup listed in a Dockerfile.

Strictly speaking, **no**. However, you can create a new image from an existing container using the [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) command:

```
$ docker commit <container-name> <image-name>
```

This command will create a new image from the existing container that you can push and pull from/to registries, export and import and create new containers from.

> The reason I ask is because I imagine there is some amount of headache involved with porting shell commands, file changes for configs, etc. to correct Dockerfile syntax and have them work correctly? But as a novice with Docker I could be overestimating the difficulty of that task.

If you're already using some other mechanism for automated configuration, you can simply integrate your existing automation into the Docker build. For instance, if you are already configuring your images using shell scripts, simply add a build step in your Dockerfile in which to add your install scripts to the container and execute it. In theory, this can also work with configuration management utilities like Puppet, Salt and others.

> EDIT: I suppose another valid reason for having the Dockerfile with each setup step is for documentation as to the initial state of the container. As opposed to being given a container in a certain state, but not necessarily having a way to know what all was done from the container's image base state.

True. As mentioned in comments, there are clear advantages to have an **automated and reproducible build** of your image. If you build your containers manually and then create an image with `docker commit`, you don't necessarily know how to re-build this image at a later point in time (which may become necessary when you want to release a new version of your application or re-build the image on top of an updated base image).